# Redirect an URL which points to a www.mydomain.com/subfolder to www.mydomain.com

Tags: url, iis-7, redirect

Hy there

Is there any posibility to redirect an URL like "www.mydomain.com/subfolder" to www.mydomain.com"

I'm using a windows server and have the posibility to use IIS7 to do that. Does I need IIS for doing that or is there an easier way?

What I exactly want:

I have installed a CMS on /subfolder, and now the CMS is reachable under "www.mydomain.com/subfolder" but I want to have the CMS under "www.mydomain.com"

How is that possible?

thank's in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to use IIS - you can just point IIS to use that subfolder as the root of the site in the Basic Settings dialog.

[alt text http://markashleybell.com/othercontent/img/iis.gif](http://markashleybell.com/othercontent/img/iis.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with IIS 7, but what you're searching for can easily be done using mod_rewrite. Of course, mod_rewrite is meant for Apache but there's also a ported version of it for IIS 7. Take a look at [URL Rewrite module for IIS7](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/05/31/urlrewrite-module-for-iis7.aspx)

Best wishes,
Fabian